# Hashing a list of emails containing multiple columns

Tags: bash, hash

I have a text file that 2 columns: ID and Email Address. I want to output a file that reads each line and outputs the ID along with the sha256 hashed version of the email.

Input example:

```
200015 jhon.smith@gmail.com
200016 larry.power@gmail.com
```

Output file:

```
200015  ae40fc9f2cf25b2b9f3cc89020ece6dd01015631d5c87483dcd3cd0c296b5eeb
200016  e420b22e7b6601ce3f416f059626688b5bc01f2c108e05798b9df4f83da3f991
```

I am using the following code:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d " \t\n\r" | sha256sum | cut -f1 -d' '
done < file_name
```

This only outputs the hashed emails. How can I adapt the code to include the IDs?

Comment: The simplest option is probably to just store the sha256 hash as a variable and then extract and concatenate the id with the hash

Comment: My latest solution: reading each line in a while loop, storing the item of a line in an array, print array[0] and the hash of array[1]. Cant seem to get the right implementation in bash

Comment: @KarimZ Why did you add the `tr` in the pipeline? If you have dos line endings then it's better to get rid of them **outside** of the loop, for example with `done < <(sed 's/\r$//' file_name)`. For the rest, the `read` command should get rid of the unneeded spaces tabs and newlines.

Comment: Trial and error; I was validating the sha256 hash code via an online software - adding tr -d " \t\n\r" provided the right hashing syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
while read -r ID EMAIL
do
  echo "$ID $( echo "$EMAIL" |tr -d " \t\n\r"| sha256sum | cut -f1 -d' ')"
done < file_name
```